# How to get all orders of current user in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get all orders made by current user inside a plugin function.

I'm using this:

```
    function get_all_orders(){
        $customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
            'numberposts' => $order_count,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
            'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
        ) ) );
   return $customer_orders;
  }
```

This works well inside theme but inside custom plugin it doesn't return anything.
Am i doing something wrong? Should i call some WooCommerce class first?

Comment: I have test your code in a plugin, activate it, and is just working perfectly without any needs, on front end. Your problem is somewhere else…

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The API might have changed since the original question, but this is a lot more elegant and uses WC’s own functions:

```
$args = array(
    'customer_id' => $user_id,
    'limit' => -1, // to retrieve _all_ orders by this user
);
$orders = wc_get_orders($args);
```

You can use [many more other $args](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query).

Comment: This looks good, but be sure to set `limit => -1` if you want _all_ of the orders without pagination.

Answer (score 2):

```
    if (!class_exists('WooCommerce')) :
        require ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php';
        $orders = get_all_orders();
    endif;

    function get_all_orders() {
        $customer_orders = get_posts(apply_filters('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value' => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_type' => wc_get_order_types('view-orders'),
            'post_status' => array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses())
                )));
        return $customer_orders;
    }
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 0):

I want to advise against the function `wc_get_orders` for large databases with lots of orders. While this will give you the result you are looking for, the sql query it generates is insanely slow.

We used this on a t3.medium database instance on AWS and we were getting 100+ seconds for the generated query to return the results.

Not sure if there are proper Woocommerce functions to do this efficiently but here is how we got a users orders.

**Functions to query the Woocommerce tables**

```php
/**
 * Woocommerce allows users to purchase products without creating an account.
 * They store the email and other details in the customer lookup table giving them a customer id.
 * Use this function if you need to get orders for a customer that does not have a user account.
 */
function my_get_customer_by_email($email)
{
  global $wpdb;
  $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_customer_lookup WHERE email = %s", $email);
  if (!$sql) {
    return new WP_Error('Error in customer query');
  }
  return $wpdb->get_row($sql);
}

function my_get_customer_by_user_id($id)
{
  global $wpdb;
  $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_customer_lookup WHERE user_id = %d", $id);
  if (!$sql) {
    return new WP_Error('Error in customer query');
  }
  return $wpdb->get_row($sql);
}

/**
 * Get all orders by a customer
 */
function my_get_customers_orders($customer_id)
{
  global $wpdb;
  $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_order_stats WHERE customer_id = %d", $customer_id);
  if (!$sql) {
    return new WP_Error('Error in order query');
  }
  return $wpdb->get_results($sql);
}

/**
 * Get all completed orders by a customer
 */
function my_get_completed_customers_orders($customer_id)
{
  global $wpdb;
  $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_order_stats WHERE customer_id = %d AND status='wc-completed'", $customer_id);
  if (!$sql) {
    return new WP_Error('Error in order query');
  }
  return $wpdb->get_results($sql);
}
```

Here is an example on how to use the previous functions:

```php
// get the customer by the users id
$customer = my_get_customer_by_user_id($user_id);
if(is_wp_error($customer)) {
  // handle possible sql error here
  // error_log($customer->get_error_message());
}

if(!$customer) {
  // handle customer not found logic here
}

$orders = my_get_customers_orders($customer->customer_id);
```

If you need these to be `WC_Order` objects you can add this additional logic:

```php
function map_orders_to_objects($o) {
  return new WC_Order($o->order_id);
}

$wc_orders = array_map('map_orders_to_object', $orders);

// you now have access to the orders line items
foreach($orders as $order) {
  $items = $order->get_items();
  // do something with the items
}
```

We went from 100+ seconds down to about 1s (estimated) just to get a customers orders. It was magnitudes faster than using `wc_get_orders`. Any query, that needs to query an indexable item, like a `customer_id` in the `postsmeta` table or any `meta` table should be avoided. Wordpress functions give you so many tools to shoot yourself in the foot for convenience.